# Garderie du/de matin, garderie matin, garderie matinale

Tags: articles, absence-d-article, complément-de-nom

Je pense qu'il s'agit d'une incompréhension plutôt classique ; je me suis déjà posé une telle question.
Je comprends les fondamentaux mais je ne suis pas toujours à l'aise pour les appliquer.
Il faut dire

> la garderie du matin

et pas

> la garderie de matin

En effet, mes enfants me corrigent en me disant que la deuxième appellation n'est pas correcte. Pourquoi ?

De plus, pourquoi ne peut-on pas dire

> la garderie matinale

ou bien tout simplement et concisément :

> garderie matin

?

Comment: Garderie du matin... chagrin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Garderie **du** matin* est une exception partagée avec *garderie **de l**'après-midi*.

La plupart et peut-être toutes les autres combinaisons de ce style ne prennent pas d'article après la préposition ***de***:

> *Garderie **de** jour*

> *Garderie **de** nuit*

> *Garderie **de** midi*

> *Garderie **de** week-end*

> *Garderie **de** semaine*

On retrouve la même impossibilité avec *travailler* et *voyager* : *Je travaille/je voyage **de** jour, **de** nuit* mais pas *je travaille/je voyage <s>**de** matin</s>*. C'est en revanche possible avec l'adjectif *bon* en apposition : *Je travaille **de bon** matin*.

***Garderie matinale*** est moins courant mais se [dit](https://archives.aubervilliers.fr/La-garderie-matinale). Il n'y a pas de différence de sens avec ***garderie du matin***.

***Garderie matin*** pourrait éventuellement être utilisé dans un message de style télégraphique ou un SMS, mais pas vraiment à l'oral ou dans un écrit soigné.

Answer (score 1):

1. La raison évidente est que les noms en français sont utilisés avec un article (qui n'est pas l'article zéro comme c'est le cas pour beaucoup de noms anglais); on dit donc « le matin »; comme la garderie est celle qui a lieu le matin on devrait dire « la garderie de le matin », mais comme cette combinaison (de le ) est toujours contracté en « du » on se retrouve avec « la garderie du matin ».
2. « Matinal »<sup>1</sup> n'est pas utilisé dans ce cas; c'est n'est tout simplement pas idiomatique; cela aurait pu être un choix mais il n'a pas été fait.  « matinal »  quand il est utilisé pour les êtres vivants signifie « qui se lève tôt » mais cela n'a rien à voir avec l'usage dans « garderie du matin ».
3. On ne dit pas la « garderie matin » parce qu'en français on ne construit pas beaucoup de noms composés de cette façon et que l'on utilise le plus souvent une préposition; par exemple pour le mot « clapier » on peut dire « cage à lapins » mais pas « cage lapin ».
   Pas de « morning nursery » en français!

<sup>1</sup><sub>Après une correction par @Laurent S.</sub>

Comment: Merci. Mais on dit le projet de recherche et pas le projet de la recherche. Gestion de projet et pas du projet, non ?

Comment: Probablement parce que l'on parle de la "gestion d'un projet" (n'importe lequel). On pourrait dire aussi la "gestion du projet" mais ça voudrait dire que l'on parle d'un projet bien particulier.

Comment: @LaurentG. Merci ! C'est bon.

Comment: @dimitris Dans ces cas-là il ne s'agit pas d'une recherche en particulier; s'il s'agissait d'une recherche en particulier les deux seraient possibles : le projet de la recherche est alors un projet de recherche particulier. Pourquoi alors ne dit-on pas « garderie de matin » ? On pourrait le dire mais ce n'est pas ce qui a été choisi par les contributeurs au langage; on dit par exemple « les fêtes de fin d'année ». Il existe parfois plusieurs possibilités mais cela ne veut pas dire qu'à toutes corresponde une forme utilisable; cela fait partie du problème de ce qui est ou non idiomatique.

Comment: Parfait. Est-ce que tu as des conseils à donner comment un locuteur non natif peut distinguer rapidement entre, e.g., garderie du matin et garderie de matin ou bien entre les fêtes de fin d'année et les fêtes de la fin d'année ou bien les fêtes de fin de l'année ?

Comment: @dimitris Malheureusement, non; je ne crois pas qu'il ait beaucoup de principes utiles pour savoir ces choses-là; il faut s'habituer aux usages particuliers par la pratique.

Comment: Ok, c'est noté. Je vais faire confiance à mes enfants :-)! Merci encore.

Comment: Il est faux de dire que matinal ne signifie pas "du matin". Une réunion qui se tient à 10h est une réunion matinale. Mais effectivement, qualifiant un individu, "matinal" signifie que cette personne se lève tôt. On pourrait dire que quelqu'un de matinal peut dès lors avoir beaucoup d'activités matinales.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, c'est exact, le sens « du matin » semble même être plus important  et celui qui aurait été le premier donné à ce mot. Merci de rectifier cela.